# Got error 'Primary script unknown' with Apache alias outside document root

Tags: php, linux, apache, proxy, debian

I've setup an Apache alias on a subdomain, which points to a directory outside the document root like this:

```
Alias / /home/keyhelp/www/webmail/plugins/xcalendar/caldav/

<Directory "/home/keyhelp/www/webmail/plugins/xcalendar/caldav">
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

This works as expected with a index.html file but not with index.php even if there is a .htaccess in the directory leading all requests to index.php.

In the Apache error log I get:

```
[Thu Mar 31 08:50:08.574396 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 376501:tid 140039026099968] [client XX.XX.XXX.XXX:58410] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'
```

System: Debian 11.3, Apache 2.4.53, PHP 7.4.28

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

So it turned out to be a permission issue. I found [this thread](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/using-the-apache-alias-directive-with-php-fpm-served-by-apache.338059/) which helped me to track down the issue, as I'm also using php-fpm. I needed to add the executable bit for others on the keyhelp directory, which was the only directory in the tree without this bit set, by using:

```
chmod +x /home/keyhelp
```

And I needed to add the path `/home/keyhelp/www` to the `open_basedir` config of php. Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the line `SetHandler application/x-httpd-php` needed to be removed from Apache config file.
You may need to add
`<Directory /var/www/yourdirectory> DirectoryIndex index.php </Directory>` 
Hope this helps someone.